# Is it possible to send voice messages over XMPP?

Tags: matrix, xmpp, messaging, ejabberd, p2p

I'm going to set up any open-source XMPP server such as ejabberd or prosody to use it within a small group of people like a working chat with no federation. XMPP client monocles claims it supports voicemails. At the same time I've found no solution for transferring files like images or voice messages in XMPP. Is there such a solution? Or should I move to another technology like matrix? The only condition is peer-to-peer encrypted messaging with an ability to transfer images/voice messages. Voice calls are not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no solution for transferring files like images or voice messages in XMPP

Really? Gajim's chat window has an clip button to send and  random local file (text, image, whatever). Obviously many other XMPP clients have file transfer support.

> The only condition is peer-to-peer encrypted messaging

As seen in https://gajim.org/

> End-to-End Encryption Chat securely using OMEMO, PGP, or OpenPGP.

If Gajim has it, then other clients do it too

I propose you:

1. Install ejabberd or prosody in your desktop machine (there are installers, container images, packages for the most common operating systems)
2. Try several well-known clients (Gajim, Conversations, Psi...) to check if the features you want are available as you desire.
3. If the feature work with some clients, then check if they work correctly in Monocles Chat.

Comment: Obviously I was wrong and did a wrong ejabberd configuration. Actually transferring files (images, video, voice) through XMPP is being possible by XMPP extension. In case of ejabberd it is mod_http_upload. No it is working well with me and the problem was caused by a closed port.